# Bluetooth file transfer says "The request could not be honored"

Tags: windows, bluetooth, android, file-transfer, mobile-phone

When I try to send a file to my DROIDX phone using the default Windows bluetooth file transfer utility, I get a message that reads "The request could not be honored" and I am unable to transfer the file. How is this overcome?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen with any file, or only certain file(s)?  IE: can you transfer a .JPG or an .MP3?

Comment: Any file regardless of type.

Comment: I ended up resolving it by downloading an app called "Bluetooth File Transfer" (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp). I would like to know how it's done without an app, though.

Answer (score -1):

move the file from current place  *if it is in desktop try to store it again in document folder and resend it again from document directly to phone by using Bluetooth..
plz, feed me back

Comment: Should this have been a comment? Can you expand your answer to explain why you think this will help?